# jQuery mixed results in IE, FireFox, Safari

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

http://jsfiddle.net/scgrant327/TkrHe/

This seems to work OK in IE, but not Firefox or Safari.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in FireFox if you add `overflow: hidden` to `.header`'s styles.